# Why has my exchange with zenbikes disappeared?

Tags: discussion

Is there a standard place where deletion of posts or comments to posts can be noted?

I ask because [this question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/9026/replacing-the-fulcrum-lever-of-a-sturmey-archer-hub-with-something-else) is now devoid of the important information (which I added to it) which corrects "zenbikes" assertion that a photo of the dropout adds more information.  The important thing about this answer is that it is possible to replace one fitting kit with another.  Something which was difficult to determine.

It's very offputting to have put work into finding and sharing the answer to this question and now to have no way of finding out where my exchange with "zenbike" has gone.

I would dispute "zenbike's" assertion that asking and answering one's own questions is a waste of anyone's time.  For further explicit confirmation of such reasoning see [SE's own blog entry](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) (linked from the bicycles.SE FAQ):

> To be crystal clear, it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own
>   question, it is explicitly encouraged.

Again, it's offputting that: 1)"zenbikes" has argued twice that asking and answering one's own questions is a waste of time; 2) that my informative, courteous exchange with him which corrected him on the factual point has now disappeared.

Comment: Why are you putting the name zenbike in quotes?

Answer (score 3):

That exchange "disappeared" because we both said we were finished talking about it, and I cleaned up the comment stream on the page. There is nothing sinister about it.

As for asking and answering your own questions, it is ok. It is just something which doesn't encourage other users to help you. And as I tried to explain to you before, I don't have a problem with you asking and answering your own questions.

My point was that you've only asked 2 questions, ever.  And that you answered both of them yourself. If that continues to be your pattern, people may ignore your questions, because there is no satisfaction in it.  It was a friendly suggestion, not an argument.

I stopped commenting about it because you didn't listen to anything that I had to say, and so there was no point. You said in your last comment that the comments were a waste of time. I agreed, so as is my job as a moderator, I cleaned them up.

Comments are intended to be clarifying information between users. They are explicitly discouraged, especially long conversations, and are often deleted when the convo is done.

Comment: I looked at the deleted comments and I agree with zenbike's decision to delete those comments. It was a lot of back and forth that wasn't going anywhere, and it wasn't providing any useful information for anybody else.